# How can I create a folder tree in json format using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering, if it possible, to provide a folder path and let a python script scan the given folder and return a json tree with the amount of files for each folder. The tree should contain every sub-folder:

E.g. result:

```json
[{
  foldername: "folder1",
  amount_of_files: 123,
  children: [
    {
      foldername: "folder1.1",
      amount_of_files: 3,
      children: []
    },
    {
      foldername: "folder1.2",
      amount_of_files: 5,
      children: [
        {
          foldername: "folder1.2.1",
          amount_of_files: 20,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  foldername: "folder2",
  amount_of_files: 1,
  children: [
    {
      foldername: "folder2.1",
      amount_of_files: 3,
      children: [
        {
          foldername: "folder2.1.1",
          amount_of_files: 2,
          children: [
            {
              foldername: "folder2.1.1.1",
              amount_of_files: 24,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      foldername: "folder1.2",
      amount_of_files: 5,
      children: []
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please share! If not, maybe make an attempt.

Comment: I know you have an answer, but would you be open to an answer using `pandas` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` with recursion:

```
import os, json
def get_tree(path=os.getcwd()):
   return {'foldername':path, 
           'amount_of_files':sum(not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, k)) for k in os.listdir(path)),
           'children':[get_tree(os.path.join(path, k)) for k in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, k))]}


with open('folder_tree.json', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(get_tree(), f)
```

---

To produce a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing the folder name and number of files, you can use a recursive generator function:

```
def get_tree(path=os.getcwd()):
   yield {'foldername':path, 'amount_of_files':sum(not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, k)) for k in os.listdir(path))}
   for i in os.listdir(path):
      if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, i)):
         yield from get_tree(os.path.join(path, i))

with open('folder_tree.json', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(list(get_tree()), f)
```

Comment: That looks awesome. How can I safe this result to a file?

Comment: This is working great. Just as a second option, is there a way on having it in an one dimensional output, giving me a 1d list of pathnames and amount of children (folder) and files?

Comment: @T.Karter Definitely, please see my recent edit

Comment: `yield from get_tree(os.path.join(path, i))` gives me invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, I need to run it with python3. Then it is working. Thank you! The only thing, the second code is missing the amount_of_children as a amount of folders an that directory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, isfile, basename, join
from json import dumps

def folder(d):
    result = dict(
            amount_of_files=0,
            foldername=basename(d)
            )
    for each in listdir(d):
        path = join(d, each)
        if isdir(path):
            if 'children' not in result:
                result['children'] = list()
            result['children'].append(folder(path))
        if isfile(path):
            result['amount_of_files'] += 1
    return result

print(dumps(folder('.')))
```